# GitHub Contributions in the last year changed it's color from green to orange

Tags: github

Today I opened GitHub and found that the contributions section color has changed to orange!
[image: GitHub last year contricutions]
Other than that the theme and other sections are still the same.
The color is a bit concerning looking like a warning, is that a theme change for all user or I'm having and issue?

I've searched but didn't find it reported before

Comment: It is because there is Helloween ...Things should go back to normal tomorrow. Ugly colors, indeed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Halloween is a celebration observed in many countries on 31 October. So my guess is that in a couple of days it will change back from orange to green.
It got me scared when I first saw it today, but then I got it...
Happy Halloween ;)

Answer (score 1):

contributions graph will return to its normal green color on November 1